# Xamarin No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys

Tags: xamarin, provisioning-profile

I am trying to run my app locally and not through an emulator.

These are the following things that I have done:

- set up the free provisioning profile

[image]

- "trusted" my iPhone when prompted
- Enabled these settings for provisioning profile:

[image]

However, I am still getting this error when trying to run the app locally on an iPhone

> No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code
>   signing keys

What else can be done to run my app locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log into the Apple Developer [member center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) and review your certificates. Down to the left you should see the Provisioning Profiles title. Click it and you'll find a list of the profiles you have. Now you need to create one with the same app identifier that your app has in Xamarin (you find it in the Info.plist file).
After that you need to open XCode and download it through Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts.
 Clean, rebuild and debug Xamarin project and try again.

Comment: This did not work. I followed the exact same steps, yet the error persists

Answer (score 0):

Go to xcode/preference/ account add a apple ID if you don have any...if you have double click in the name ...and look the name appear in iOS Team Provisioning Profile.
Now open in xamarin the info.plist and in Bundle Identifier put this name.
and now should load a provisional profile.

Comment: what if we did not pay for apple developer program? How do you do that