# No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to launch my test app to a real iOS device through iOS xamarin. However, upon building or deploying, the error notes:

`No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities`

I have followed every step concerning creating certificates for the app, partitioning devices, creating an apple developer account and linking to Xcode, yet this error persists...

**update:**

I revoked the certificate an recreated the provisioning file, now downloaded through Xcode. However, Xamarin can now build, but not deploy out to my iPhone as there is no Run option:

[image]

How can this be alleviated?

Comment: @Sneak I have followed everything in that answer. The error persists

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474495/xamarin-no-installed-provisioning-profiles-match-the-installed-ios-code-signing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410019/xamarin-no-installed-provisioning-profiles-match-the-installed-ios-signing-ident for more and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626057/no-installed-provisioning-profiles-match-the-installed-ios-code-signing-keys threads

Comment: Check the threads I linked now, you have everything set correctly? If you do, update the question what you have checked etc on other threads, and what is not working I will retract the duplicate flag.

Comment: @Sneak can you see my update

Comment: I have upvoted you and retracted the duplicate flag for the edit, however, maybe you should edit the question title too since now you have the intial problem solved and you run into a completely different problem. **EDIT** I see that you created a new question regarding that. You should remove the edit from this then as it was solved or maybe even better, delete this question.